# Why would IIS user connected as another user to that which they used to login to Windows

Tags: windows, iis, authentication

I am using Windows Authentication on a website / WCF service.  In WCF I am using HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name to do some authorization.

2 users out of 50 seem to be hitting IIS under a different security context to that which they are logged into Windows.  In both cases they are "Domain\Administrator" instead of their real "Domain\User" account.

It isn't WCF specific or anything to do with my WCF client code, as after the problem arose I asked the 2 users to hit a simple html page in their browser, and the IIS logs show them connecting as Administrator as well.

Aside from getting them to reboot and watching them type in their Windows logins to be sure, I checked that their browsers weren't set to 'Run as Administrator', which is an option if you look at the properties of the IE link (shortcut tab-> Advanced button) (not the internet options).

Answer (score 0):

If the users have UAC turned off and are in the local Administrators group then IE will no longer run in sandbox mode (even if you don't choose 'Run as Adminstrator' on the shortcut) and will run in the Administrator user context.  Check the UAC settings to see if they are disabled.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I can't get on the user's machine right now, but in the IIS logs the user is hitting the server as domain\administrator not machine\administrator... Is that what you expect in that UAC scenario?

Comment: After re-reading your question, perhaps you can clarify the scenario based on this example: domain\joe logs into his PC.  He hits your ASP site and when you do an examination of the IIS logs you see him hitting the site as machine\joe instead of domain\joe.  Also, HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name reports machine\joe instead of domain\joe. Is this correct?